# conditional editing in django model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to find a way to update fields values automatically like when a user update the Type field ,  Action, Status and finish time fields get updated also.for example:

```
if Type == 'On store': Then
Action == 'Requested' 
Status == 'Pending'
Time_Finished == Today
```

The model goes like this

```
class order(models.Model):
   Time_Registered = models.DateField(blank=False)
   Number = models.CharField(max_length=500)
   Type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
   Action = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, choices=ACTION)
   Status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   Time_Finished = models.DateField(blank=False)

class Status(models.Model): class Meta: verbose_name_plural = "Status" 
   ID = models.IntegerField(max_length=250) status = 
   models.CharField(max_length=250)  # and it contain : Three values Pending , Under Process and Delivered
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override you Model `save()` method :

```
class order(models.Model):
   Time_Registered = models.DateField(blank=False)
   Number = models.CharField(max_length=500)
   Type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
   Action = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, choices=ACTION)
   Status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   Time_Finished = models.DateField(blank=False)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      if self.Type == 'On store':
         self.Action = 'Requested' 
         self.Status = Status.objects.get(status='Pending')
         self.Time_Finished = datetime.utcnow()
      super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

For automatically settled dates, you can also take a look at `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` `DateField` attributes

Comment: I tried it. worked fine for all fields except the status what is this mean< your request to get 'Pending' element> ?

Comment: self.Status represent a `Model` instance, not a python simple type. You need to write the right `Django.object.get(...)` request to retrieve this Model instance from DB. Give me the shape of `Status` model, and I could help you more

Comment: lass Status(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Status"
    ID = models.IntegerField(max_length=250)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=250)
and it contain :  Three values  Pending , Under Process and Dilevered

Comment: You can edit your own post, better for further readers. I've edited mine. Don't forget to vote ;)